# Strange maven exception: java.lang.LinkageError:loader constraint violation

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat

I have searched a lot of related questions in Stack Overflow,but it still can't solve my problem, because the problem is too strange!

I am developing a B2C system using maven project (spring+springmvc+mybatis). I divide my project into several parts: taotao-parent (the parent project in maven),   taotao-common (some util class)  and taotao-manager-web (packaging to war).

I define all the dependcyManagement in taotao_parent, like this:
taotao-parent/pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.taotao</groupId>
  <artifactId>taotao-parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <properties>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <mybatis.version>3.2.8</mybatis.version>
        <mybatis.spring.version>1.2.2</mybatis.spring.version>
        <mybatis.paginator.version>1.2.15</mybatis.paginator.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.32</mysql.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
        <jackson.version>2.4.2</jackson.version>
        <druid.version>1.0.9</druid.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.3.5</httpclient.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet-api.version>2.5</servlet-api.version>
        <jsp-api.version>2.0</jsp-api.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.5</joda-time.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.3.2</commons-lang3.version>
        <commons-io.version>1.3.2</commons-io.version>
        <commons-net.version>3.3</commons-net.version>
        <pagehelper.version>3.4.2-fix</pagehelper.version>
        <jsqlparser.version>0.9.1</jsqlparser.version>
        <commons-fileupload.version>1.3.1</commons-fileupload.version>
        <jedis.version>2.7.2</jedis.version>
        <solrj.version>4.10.3</solrj.version>
        <dubbo.version>2.5.3</dubbo.version>
        <zookeeper.version>3.4.7</zookeeper.version>
        <zkclient.version>0.1</zkclient.version>
        <activemq.version>5.11.2</activemq.version>
        <freemarker.version>2.3.23</freemarker.version>
        <quartz.version>2.2.2</quartz.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-net.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- httpclient -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
                <version>${quartz.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Mybatis -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
                <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${mybatis.spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.miemiedev</groupId>
                <artifactId>mybatis-paginator</artifactId>
                <version>${mybatis.paginator.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.pagehelper</groupId>
                <artifactId>pagehelper</artifactId>
                <version>${pagehelper.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- MySql -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>${mysql.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
                <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
                <version>${druid.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- <dependency>
                <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>${jstl.version}</version>
            </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jsp-api.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-fileupload.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
                <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
                <version>${jedis.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
                <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
                <version>${solrj.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
                <artifactId>dubbo</artifactId>
                <version>${dubbo.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
                <version>${zookeeper.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.sgroschupf</groupId>
                <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
                <version>${zkclient.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
                <version>${activemq.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <!-- <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement> -->
</project>
```

and some util classes in taotao-common:
taotao-common/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.taotao</groupId>
    <artifactId>taotao-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.taotao</groupId>
  <artifactId>taotao-common</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
          </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- httpclient -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and last, taotao-manager-web(service war, can run in tomcat):

taotao-manager-web/pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.taotao</groupId>
    <artifactId>taotao-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.taotao</groupId>
  <artifactId>taotao-manager-web</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <webVersion>3.0</webVersion>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.taotao</groupId>
          <artifactId>taotao-common</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
                <port>8199</port>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

when l input `tomcat7:run` ,tomcat is running:

but when l input http:localhost:8119/ , error ocurred:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/index_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/realm/ClassRealm) for the method's defining class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/el/ExpressionFactory used in the signature] with root cause
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/index_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/realm/ClassRealm) for the method's defining class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/el/ExpressionFactory used in the signature
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:31)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I add `<score>provided</scope>` to servlet-api and jsp-api, but it is still wrong.

Comment: Could you update your question with your index.jsp, please?

Comment: sorry! in webapp/index.jsp has only a word: welcome to taotao. so l have not showed it.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem copying the content of these POMs, but I couldn't. The app ran well. Could you try to create a proof of concept runnable and upload into github or some paste-code web app?

Comment: oh.well. l will upload the project to my github.

Comment: This is your local SVN. Take your time to upload a reproducable proof of concept on Github. You just need to follow some guide or tutorial on internet. It's not hard and I think it's the best approach :)

Comment: https://github.com/Javacppc/taotaobbs  ok   there is another part: taotao-manager---it provides the service to taotao-manager-web. but l think it has no effect on this question,so l haven't showed it on stackoverflow.

Comment: The project ran without problems. So what I recommend you is that you clear your maven home (usually is at ~/.m2/repository).

Comment: If this solved your question, let me know so I can write a proper answer.

Comment: unfortunately, it is always wrong. it's the same problem .l tried to change another repostory.but it's still wrong.it's so strange.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you are using the file index.jsp in the root of the project because tomcat will try to resolve it first, if you are using another template engine, you need to take out this.